# Registering Push Notifications for OneSignal after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

I need push notifications for CloudKit, so I don't want to ask the user for notifications permission on the first launch of the app. I only want to ask the user at the point where the permission is actually needed. So I am adding two buttons on an in-app Settings controller - one that allows the user to setup CloudKit and one that allows the user to enable Push Notifications if they have not yet been enabled. The issue comes in with the way that OneSignal is supposed to be setup. The setup is supposed to happen in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, and the method used (`setupOneSignalWithLaunchOptions:`) requires the `launchOptions` parameter. Is there a way to setup OneSignal from a viewController within the app, as opposed to from the App Delegate?

EDIT: I am thinking I can save launchOptions and use them when I am ready to setup OneSignal at a later time. In subsequent launches of the app, `setupOneSignalWithLaunchOptions:` would be called as intended, in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. But when the user initially enables notifications, I will use the saved `launchOptions`, because the app might not be launched again for some time (it does run in the background).

Comment: Your edit is what I would suggest your do. Another alternative is to explore the `launchOptions` dictionary to see what's in there, maybe you can replicate it easily, though I would suggest storing the one you get from `UIApplication` because if it changes in the future it won't break your app's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OneSignal SDK has a setting called `kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt`. You can pass in a value of `false` for this setting when you initialize the library using:

`+ (id)initWithLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions appId:(NSString*)appId handleNotificationAction:(OSHandleNotificationActionBlock)actionCallback settings:(NSDictionary*)settings;`

This will cause the alert prompt not to appear and you can instead trigger it later by calling:

`+ (void)promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse:(void(^)(BOOL accepted))completionHandler;`

More info: https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--kossettingskeyautoprompt-

Comment: Ok, so I can setup OneSignal regardless of if the user will opt to receive push notifications later or not, right? That is very helpful. The issue with promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse: , though, is that I need to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications] because OneSignal is not the only API that will be using push/remote notifications.

Comment: I probably need to post a new question about using registerForRemoteNotifications in lieu of promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to post a new question for that.